# How to treat $\nabla \cdot \left ( \frac{\vec{r}}{\left | \vec{r} \right |^{3}} \right )= 4\pi \delta \left ( \vec{r} \right )$ numerically?

Tags: numerical-methods, distribution-theory, numerical-calculus

In electrodynamics we have $\nabla \cdot \left ( \frac{\vec{r}}{\left | \vec{r} \right |^{3}} \right )= 4\pi \delta \left ( \vec{r} \right )$, my question is how to use numerical method to treat this formula so that we can address the cases in which the singularity exists with the help of computer

Comment: How is $\delta(0)$ defined?

Comment: @BEIRUT  it is dirac delta distribution, it is a linear functional which maps a compactly support real-vauled smooth function to it's value at 0

Comment: @BEIRUT  you can check this wiki entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function

Comment: It shouldn't be $\delta(0)$. It should be $\delta(\vec r)$, $\delta_0(\vec r)$ or $\delta(\vec r-\vec 0)$.

Comment: One can treat $\pi\delta(0)$ as a divergent integral (via Laplace and Fourier transforms). But notice that this treatment should be considered purely formal, as it is just what you get if you insert $0$ into some formulas.

Comment: @md2perpe I have corrected it

Comment: Could you give more context? I assume that you discretize space in some way. How? Just as a grid?

Comment: @YuerWu What do you mean by "treat this formula"? What do you want to know? What do you want to compute? So far you just gave an equation, but it is not clear, what you want to do with it.